# Select from other column if primary column is empty (coalesce)

Tags: magento-1.9, database, reports

I try to extend Abandoned Carts report. In order to do that I need to modify a query that is used to populate the grid. I can't prepare `coalesce` condition using `Varien_Db_Select`.

Now there is:

```
// Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Quote_Collection::addCustomerData($filter = null)
$this->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        array('cust_email' => $attrEmailTableName),
        'cust_email.entity_id = main_table.customer_id',
        array('email' => 'cust_email.email')
    )
//...
$this->_joinedFields['email']         = 'cust_email.email';
//...

// Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Shopcart_Abandoned_Grid::_prepareColumns()
$this->addColumn('email', array(
    'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Email'),
    'index'     =>'email',
    'sortable'  =>false
));
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, (main_table.base_subtotal_with_discount*main_table.base_to_global_rate) AS `subtotal`, `cust_email`.`email`, `cust_fname`.`value` AS `firstname`, `cust_mname`.`value` AS `middlename`, `cust_lname`.`value` AS `lastname`, CONCAT_WS(' ', cust_fname.value, cust_mname.value, cust_lname.value) AS `customer_name`
FROM `sales_flat_quote` AS `main_table`
LEFT JOIN `customer_entity` AS `cust_email` ON cust_email.entity_id = main_table.customer_id
LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `cust_fname` ON cust_fname.entity_id = main_table.customer_id AND cust_fname.attribute_id = 1
LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `cust_mname` ON cust_mname.entity_id = main_table.customer_id AND cust_mname.attribute_id = 827
LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `cust_lname` ON cust_lname.entity_id = main_table.customer_id AND cust_lname.attribute_id = 2
WHERE (`items_count` != '0') AND (`main_table`.`is_active` = '1')
```

I would like to have in column `email`:

```
COALESCE(cust_email.email, main_table.customer_email)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and after some digging came up with this as the solution:

```
$this->getSelect()->columns('COALESCE(cust_email.email, main_table.customer_email)');
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433176/select-only-specific-fields-in-magento